# Metro plug-in for Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, java-metro-framework

Where can I find a tutorial to install and use a Metro plug-in to Eclipse Juno? I have to migrate a sample with ant (downloaded with metro 2.3 libraries) in a dynamic web project Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: Important: I use Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Metro plug-in for Eclipse Juno, but [GlassFish Tools for Juno](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-java-ee-application-server-plugin-eclipse) available at Eclipse's marketplace. If you are willing to try it, there is an [official tutorial](http://metro.java.net/2.3/guide/ch02.html#developing-with-eclipse) for Metro-on-Eclipse available here.

However, you have mentioned in the comment that you are not using Glassfish, but Tomcat, so I would recommend different approach. Follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) and be careful when deploying the service - you will have to edit `web.xml` and `sun-jaxws.xml` files, together with installing JAX-WS (or Metro) libraries on Tomcat.